# Cannot clear text in input text field in Ionic

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm new at Ionic and Angular. I try to create a post status like Facebook, my first task is when the user types any text and press the POST button I want the text in the input field to disappear, but it disappears in the first time when this view is a new load.

When I try to type any text in the input field and press the POST button, the text won't disappear but function in the controller was called. Past, I use `label` tag but when I press the POST button `ng-click` didn't work so I change `label` tag to `div` tag but it work at the first time as I say above and I include cache is false it didn't work too. Here is my [`Plunker`](http://plnkr.co/edit/4qF9EV?p=preview), This issue is in Chat view.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The ng-model should be bound to an object and not to an variable.

The means the the declaration of the variable should be something like:

```
 $scope.input = {
    saySomething : 'Some question'

  };
```

The input field should then be:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Say Something" ng-model="input.saySomething"/>
```

Comment: Wow, it work like magic. Thank you very much for saving my life. By the way, Does issue is about primitive and non-primitive or just Ionic mechanism?

Comment: The issue is not ionic specific. It's Angular. (Can you mark my awnser as the one that resolved is:) )

Comment: Life status : saved, props to you Toxus